# MYSQL query save array of results as variables

Tags: php, sql, database

im after the simplest (and easiest to understand from a novice programmers perspective) to do the following;

I have a query on a database:

```
$newsquery = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3');
```

I want to to select the top three rows in my table and get the column 'news'

Then I need to save each result as a separate variable, this could be $news1, $news2 and $news3

So i could then use these variables to echo as needed on my page.

I hope this makes sense, many thanks .

Comment: You probably have to add the tag that refer to the langage in use, looks like php, to have better visibility on SO.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php  example #1 and #2

Answer (score 0):

stop using `mysql` as `PHP` is removing it at the end of the year,use `PDO` or `mysqli`

```
$rows = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($newsquery)) {
$rows[] = $row['news'];
}
$news1 = $rows[0];
$news2 = $rows[1];
$news3 = $rows[2;
```

with `PDO`

```
$rows = $results->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$news1 = $rows[0]['news'];
$news2 = $rows[1]['news'];
$news3 = $rows[2]['news'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you used `mysql`, I will give the answer in mysql itself.

```
$newarray = array(); 
$newsquery = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3');

while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $newsquery ))
{
    $new_array[] = $row; // Inside while loop
}
```

OR use the below code

```
$newarray = array(); 
$newsquery = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3');

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($newsquery)) 
{
    $new_array[$row['newsid']]['newsid'] = $row['newsid'];
    $new_array[$row['newsid']]['data'] = $row['data'];
}
```

To get each column value

```
foreach($new_array as $array)
{       
   echo $array['newsid'].'<br />';
   echo $array['data'].'<br />';
}
```